# check if particular string is present in a sentence

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to check some string in a row in a sentence using if condition but i'm not getting the expected the output. I've also tried with the Regex pattern but that is also not helping me out. Can anyone help me with this? My value for string changes everytime so not sure if this is the problem.

```
r="Carnival: monitor service-eu Beta cloudwatch_module" 
  if "Carnival: monitor service-eu Beta" in r:
            test_string="EU"
            test_string1="eu"
        elif "Carnival: monitor service-na Beta" in r:
            test_string="NA"
            test_string1="na"
        elif "Carnival: monitor service-fe Beta" in r:
            test_string="FE"
            test_string1="fe"
        else:
            print("None found")
```

With regex something like this.

but this is also not working.

```
re_pattern = r'\b(?:service-eu|Beta|monitor|Carnival)\b'
new_= re.findall(re_pattern, r)
new1_=new_[2]
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

If isn't necessary use this *short_description* function, I suggest you use the *find* function:

```
if r.find("Carnival: monitor service-eu Beta") != -1:
 test_string="EU"
 test_string1="eu"
elif r.find("Carnival: monitor service-na Beta") != -1:
 test_string="NA"
 test_string1="na"
elif r.find("Carnival: monitor service-fe Beta") != -1:
 test_string="FE"
 test_string1="fe"
else:
 print("None found")
```

Comment: Not working, My `r` is string here though

Comment: Some error occur? What is returned?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your problem, but hopefully this helps:

```py
import re

def get_string(r):
    return re.findall(r"service-[a-z]{2}",r)[0][-2:]

get_string("Carnival: monitor service-na Beta")
>>> 'na'
get_string("Carnival: monitor service-fe Beta")
>>> 'fe'
```

Here, `[a-z]{2}` means any word that contains lowercase letters with a length of 2.

Comment: Ah i'm getting errors. input is string here though!
 return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pattern with a capture group and `.upper()` for the group value.

```
\bCarnival: monitor service-([a-z]{2}) Beta\b
```

See the capture group value at the [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/sH0AEV/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/xiieks).

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"\bCarnival: monitor service-([a-z]{2}) Beta\b"
r = "Carnival: monitor service-eu Beta cloudwatch_module"
m = re.search(pattern, r)
if m:
    test_string1 = m.group(1)
    test_string = test_string1.upper()

    print(test_string)
    print(test_string1)
```

Output

```
EU
eu
```